# Label freezes and doesn't change it's Left property

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically I tried to make a marquee with 2 Labels that when one goes invisible, the second one starts it's animation so it goes smooth from left to right and the text is always visible. My problem is that it does work at start but when I retry that code (second time at run time so the old animation stops, it refresh the text and start the animation again) the second label freezes when it was and it's left property of it's canvas doesn't change (Canvas.SetLeft(L_Content_Second, -L_Content_Second.ActualWidth))

## C#

it's a function called StartAnimation(); It's fired when content of L_Content and L_Content_Second changes

```
DoubleKeyFrameCollection collection = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection();
collection.Add(
new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(
    -L_Content.ActualWidth,
    KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)))
);
if (L_Content.ActualWidth > this.ActualWidth)
{
    collection.Add(
    new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(
        this.ActualWidth - (L_Content.ActualWidth / 2),
        KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)))
    );
    collection.Add(
    new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(
        this.ActualWidth * 2,
        KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
    );
}
else
{
    collection.Add(
    new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(
        this.ActualWidth - L_Content.ActualWidth,
        KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)))
    );
    collection.Add(
    new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(
        this.ActualWidth + (this.ActualWidth - L_Content.ActualWidth),
        KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
    );
}
animK.KeyFrames = collection;
animK.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

animK2.KeyFrames = collection;
animK2.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
animK2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);


animK.AutoReverse = false;
animK2.AutoReverse = false;

animK.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
animK.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
animK2.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
animK2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

Canvas.SetLeft(L_Content_Second, -L_Content_Second.ActualWidth); //This works at start, then it doesn't any more

L_Content_Second.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
L_Content.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animK, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
L_Content_Second.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animK2, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
```

## XAML

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="Supreme.Components.ScrollLabel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="18" Width="300" MouseDoubleClick="UserControl_MouseDoubleClick_1" Background="#00000000">
    <Canvas x:Name="Container">
        <Label x:Name="L_Content" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Height="18" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="L_Content_Second" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Height="18" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" SizeChanged="L_Content_SizeChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to attempt the same via XAML

below is the sample for same, run it and see if this does what you are looking for.

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="Container">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <l:PositionConverter xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"
                                 x:Key="PositionConverter" />
        <Storyboard x:Key="marquee">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="L_Content"
                                           RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                           Duration="0:0:10">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                      Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=L_Content, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5"
                                      Value="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Container}" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10"
                                      Value="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Container}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="L_Content_Second"
                                           RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                           Duration="0:0:10">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                      Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=L_Content_Second, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5"
                                      Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=L_Content_Second, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10"
                                      Value="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Container}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <TextBox x:Name="L_Content"
             Foreground="Red"
             Text="first" />
    <TextBox x:Name="L_Content_Second"
             Foreground="Green"
             Text="second">
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="Start" Canvas.Top="30">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource marquee}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="L_Content"
                      RoutedEvent="SizeChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource marquee}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="L_Content_Second"
                      RoutedEvent="SizeChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource marquee}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SizeChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource marquee}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```

I've used textbox in this example for easy value change, also for this I have created a converter

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class PositionConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return -System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```